# Como visualizo un archivo html/php en el navegador Linux [Pop!_OS]

Tags: php, html, linux

Mi problema es que no puedo visualizar un html en google.

Por ejemplo tengo creada la carpeta Tienda y dentro el archivo index.php

Si arrastro el archivo .php me lo vuelve a instalar, y si intento abrir el .php o el .html no me lo encuentra.

yo pongo localhost/Tienda/index.php  y no me abre nada Ayuda

Comment: Podrías proporcionar mas información?. no esta nada claro lo que necesitas.

Comment: podrias agregar un screenshot

Comment: ¿Instalaste software de servidor, Apache o Nginx? ¿Cuál es la ruta completa de la carpeta `Tienda`?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

1. Un archivo no se "abre" en `google`. Entiendo que quieres decir un *navegador web* como Firefox o Chrome.
2. Si **arrastras** un archivo `php` desde un *gestor de archivos gráfico* hacia un *navegador web*, suele pasar eso que dices, porque lo interpreta con este protocolo:  `file://` y por lo tanto no es servido por el servidor web que tengas instalado, sino que viene a ser tratado como un archivo de texto dentro del sistema.

En cambio, si arrastras un archivo HTML seguramente te lo abra mas o menos bien, pues contiene código HTML que el navegador es capaz de interpretar, pero no lo está sirviendo ningun servidor web.

Para abrir un archivo PHP desde un navegador debes usar el protocol `http://` o `https://` segun este configurado el servidor web. En tu caso entiendo que es `http://localhost/Tienda/index.php`, pero entonces tienes el siguiente problema que explicas.

3. `yo pongo localhost/Tienda/index.php y no me abre nada`: Bueno, no das muchas pistas, pero podrian estar sucediendote alguna de estas cosas:

3.1.) Lo estas poniendo en el campo de búsqueda de Google, y te esta mostrando los resultados de esa búsqueda, pero no lo que tienes en tu sistema

3.2 ) Si lo pones en la barra donde estan las direcciones URL quizás si que consigas acceder a su contenido correctamente. Fíjate en la imagen siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.3) Si ni con eso consigues acceder a tu archivo, podria ser porque no tienes ningun servidor web instalado en tu sistema.  Por lo tanto deberias instalarte uno, por ejemplo el más común en Linux es Apache.

3.4)  Una vez instalado Apache, asegurate que tambien instalas el soporte para PHP de Apache.

3.5) Y como último, asegúrate donde apunta tu servidor apache por defecto, es decir, la ruta interna dentro de tu sistema de archivos, por ejemplo, `/var/www/public` o algo asi, y es alli donde debes colocar todos los archivos que vayan a ser usados para tu proyecto web (html, php, etc).

No te pongo enlaces de nada porque no has proporcionado ninguna información sobre que sistema Linux estas usando, etc.  Pero puedes encontrar instrucciones de cada cosa que te he comentado buscandolo en `Google` (ahora sí que debes usar su campo de búsqueda).